# Problem in Differential Equation.

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations

$y^2\frac{dy}{dx}-2xe^{x^2+1}=0$

My attempt,

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{2e^{x^2+1}x}{y^2}$$

$$\frac{dy}{dx}y^2=2e^{x^2+1}x$$

$$\int \frac{dy}{dx}y^2 dx=\int 2e^{x^2+1}xdx$$

$$\frac{y^3}{3}=e^{x^2+1}+c_1$$

How to proceed?

Comment: Multiply by 3 and take the cube root.

Comment: that is it. you are done.

Answer (score 0):

If 
$${y^3\over 3 } = e^{x^2+1}+c_1$$ then $$y^3 = 3e^{x^2+1} + c_1'$$
and $$y=\left(3e^{x^2+1} + c_1'\right)^{1/3}$$ where $c_1'=3c_1$.

Comment: and you'll need some boundary condition to find $c_1'$

Comment: @Mathxx forget W|A

Comment: sorry i don't understand what you have written...

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=y%5E2dy%2Fdx-2xe%5E%28x%5E2%2B1%29%3D0

Why W|A showing three answers? Are they equivalent? @danimal

Comment: W|A will show three answers because a cubic equation has 3 complex solutions in general, and it will not assume you are after real solutions only unless you specify this. Presumably you are only after real solutions so you can just take the cube root "normally"